# rename multiple jpg files

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I have a directory full with time stamped webcamfiles. It start at midnight, and take a picture every minute.

*0001webcamimage.jpg

0002webcamimage.jpg

0003webcamimage.jpg

...

0059webcamimage.jpg

0100webcamimage.jpg*


Now i want to convert all the files with a batch-file to this format. The sequence is important.

*0001.jpg

0002.jpg

0003.jpg

...

0060.jpg

0061.jpg*

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can't you just use some ready-made renamer?

Comment: Do you need to use a script for this or do you want to write a program?

Comment: It's tagged "Batch-File" guys

Comment: What if the numbers in the original names do not begin with `0001`? Would you still need to start the numbering from `0001` or should the number from the first file name found be used as a starting number?

Comment: I want sequentially named files. The numbers in the original names always start at 0001 (one minute after midnight). My problem is that i have gaps. Sample: 0059webcamimage.jpg and 0100webcamimage.jpg. I don't want that. I need 0059 an then 0060.

Comment: The reason that i want this is: I use ffmpeg.exe that make a timelapse movie from the images. That program only reads sequentially named files without gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Windows & 4 digit prefixes

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*webcamimage.jpg) do (
    set name=%%f
    ren "!name!" "!name:~0,4!.jpg"
)
```

Comment: This works great. Don't forget to put this script to the same folder with photos.

Comment: something go's wrong. I get this output.

0001.jpg
0002.jpg
0003.jpg
.
.
0058.jpg
0059.jpg
0100.jpg
0101.jpg
0102.jpg


after 0059.jpg i need 0060.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The following is similar to @Alex K.'s suggestion but doesn't extract numbers from the original names. Instead, it uses a counter and forms the new names using the counter's values:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /A num=10000
FOR %%I IN (*webcamimage.jpg) DO (
  SET /A num+=1
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  RENAME "%%I" !num:~-4!.*
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

Note that the new names will always start with `0001.jpg`.

**UPDATE**

If the batch file is not in the same directory as the images, you can specify the path to them like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /A num=10000
FOR %%I IN (D:\path\to\images\*webcamimage.jpg) DO (
  SET /A num+=1
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  RENAME "%%I" !num:~-4!.*
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

Alternatively, you could add the `CD /D` command before the loop to change to the directory where the images are:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD /D D:\path\to\images
SET /A num=10000
FOR %%I IN (*webcamimage.jpg) DO (
  SET /A num+=1
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  RENAME "%%I" !num:~-4!.*
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

If, after finishing the job, you need to change back to the directory that was active before invocation of the batch file, use `PUSHD` and `POPD`:

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD D:\path\to\images
SET /A num=10000
FOR %%I IN (*webcamimage.jpg) DO (
  SET /A num+=1
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  RENAME "%%I" !num:~-4!.*
  ENDLOCAL
)
POPD
```

And, of course, you can parametrise the path as well so that you can specify it in the command line when invoking the batch file. Here's how:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "imagepath=%~1"
SET /A num=10000
FOR %%I IN ("%imagepath%\*webcamimage.jpg") DO (
  SET /A num+=1
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  RENAME "%%I" !num:~-4!.*
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

Now you can invoke the batch file at the command prompt or from another batch file like this:

```
batchname.bat D:\path\to\images
```

(In case you are not aware: if you call a batch file from another batch file, you'll likely need to add `CALL` before the name of the batch file being called, i.e. `CALL batchname parameters`.)

Comment: Thats works PERFECT!!! Now i must place the batch file in the same directory. How do i change the batch file when the images are in this directory. C:\FFMPEG\IMAGES

Comment: You could specify the path together with the `*webcamimage.jpg` mask or you could `CD /D` to that directory before the loop (alternatively, `PUSHD`, then `POPD`, if you need to come back to the directory where you are invoking the batch file from. Please see my update for details and examples.

Answer (score -1):

With linux, use rename :

```
rename 'webcamimage' '' *.jpg
```

Comment: @EitanT, I don't think so, and here's why: a) matteomattei asked the platform before this answer was posted, so there was some doubt, and b)  platform *does matter* in this case. I'm not saying Nicholas is a bad person, a poor answer-guy or anything like that, just that his answer is not applicable. The vote is for the answer, not the person.

Comment: @BryanH, Your words express my thoughts exactly. That said, this answer is not _wrong_, it's just unhelpful, and so should not be voted up (whereas explicitly wrong answers should be voted down). Of course, in the end you have the liberty to cast your vote either up or down as you see fit. Just sayin'. I do commend you for being courteous and providing a reason for your downvote.